# Java regex confusion

Tags: java, regex

I have the following (Java) code:

```
public class TestBlah {
    private static final String PATTERN = ".*\\$\\{[.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\}.*";

    public static void main(String[] s) throws IOException {
        String st = "foo ${bar}\n";

        System.out.println(st.matches(PATTERN));
        System.out.println(Pattern.compile(PATTERN).matcher(st).find());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Running this code, the former `System.out.println` outputs `false`, while the latter outputs `true`

Am I not understanding something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `.` will not match the new line character.  Thus, your String that contains a new line, will not match a string that ends with `.*`.  So, when you call `matches()`, it returns false, because the new line doesn't match.

The second one returns true because it finds a match inside the input string.  It doesn't necessarily match the whole string.

From [the `Pattern` javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> `.` Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

Comment: From the same doc: The regular expression . matches any character except a line terminator unless the DOTALL  flag is specified.

Answer (score 1):

`String.matches(..)` behaves like `Matcher.matches(..)`. From the documentation of [Matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

```
find(): Attempts to find the next subsequence of 
        the input sequence that matches the pattern.

matches(): Attempts to match the entire input sequence 
        against the pattern.
```

So you could think of `matches()` as if it surrounded your regexp with `^` and `$` to make sure the beginning of the string matches the beginning of your regular expression and the end of the string matches the end of the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between matching a pattern and finding the pattern in a String

- [`String.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) :

  > Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

  Your whole string must match the pattern.
- [`Matcher.matches()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) :

  > Attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.

  Again your whole string must match.
- [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) :

  > Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

  Here you only need a "partial match".

---

As @Justin said :
Your `matches()` can't work as the `.` won't match new line characters (`\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`).

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - String.matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))
- [Javadoc - Matcher.matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())
- [Javadoc - Matcher.find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())